# jQuery Loop through each div

Tags: jquery, loops

I'm pretty sure this will be a really easy answer for you jQuery whizzes, and I'm also pretty such it involves a loop of some kind.

I'm trying to perform essentially the same calculation on two separate divs, but assigning a different CSS width value to each id based on the number of images found. The calculations I'm performing are irrelevant to my problem really, but I put them in anyway because it's the actual code I'm working with.

Here is the markup...

```
<div id ='test1' class='target'>
  <div class='scrolling'>
    <img/>
    <img/>
    <img/>
  </div>
</div>

<div id ='test2' class='target'>
  <div class='scrolling'>
    <img/>
    <img/>
    <img/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Below is my current jQuery, which works fine, but it's inefficient because I have to write another chunk of code for every div added. How can I standardise this so that it runs through every div with the class of target? Thanks

```
/* Measure the width of each image. */
test1 = $('#div1 .scrolling img').width();
test2 = $('#div2 .scrolling img').width();

/* Find out how many images there are. */
test1img = $('#div1 .scrolling img').length;
test2img = $('#div2 .scrolling img').length;

/* Do the maths. */
final1 = (test1 * test1img)*1.2;
final2 = (test2 * test2img)*1.2;

/* Apply the maths to the CSS. */
$('#div1 .scrolling').width(final1);
$('#div2 .scrolling').width(final2);
```

Comment: I´m not sure you need to do this calculations. Have you tried to solve  it with pure CSS?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Like this:

```
$(".target").each(function(){
    var images = $(this).find(".scrolling img");
    var width = images.width();
    var imgLength = images.length;
    $(this).find(".scrolling").width( width * imgLength * 1.2 );
});
```

The `$(this)` refers to the current `.target` which will be looped through. Within this `.target` I'm looking for the `.scrolling img` and get the width. And then keep on going...

**Images with different widths**

If you want to calculate the width of all images (when they have different widths) you can do it like this:

```
// Get the total width of a collection.
$.fn.getTotalWidth = function(){
    var width = 0;
    this.each(function(){
        width += $(this).width();
    });
    return width;
}

$(".target").each(function(){
    var images = $(this).find(".scrolling img");
    var width = images.getTotalWidth();
    $(this).find(".scrolling").width( width * 1.2 );
});
```

Comment: `$(this).find(".scrolling img")` returns a collection of matched elements.

Comment: True, but the starter sayd his code works, and I currently only added the loop, so should be still working. So jQuery will just pick the first IMG it can find and returns that width.

Comment: @Stefan, yes it does. But `width()` only returns the width of the *first* element from the array of matched elements.

Comment: Ok, just saying that nothing says that all images have the same width but maybe they do.

Comment: Wow, loads of great responses here. Niel, your solution worked really well, but I'm interested in David's comment - perhaps this was an error with my original code too. What if I have images of different sizes within the .scrolling div? How can I make sure it calculates the total width? Tx

Comment: I have posted an update a few minutes ago how to get it with different widths, give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

You're right that it involves a loop, but this is, at least, made simple by use of the `each()` method:

```
$('.target').each(
    function(){
        // iterate through each of the `.target` elements, and do stuff in here
        // `this` and `$(this)` refer to the current `.target` element
        var images = $(this).find('img'),
            imageWidth = images.width(); // returns the width of the _first_ image
            numImages = images.length;
        $(this).css('width', (imageWidth*numImages));

    });
```

References:

- [`css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/).
- [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/).
- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).

Answer (score 1):

```
$('div.target').each(function() {
   /* Measure the width of each image. */
   var test = $(this).find('.scrolling img').width();

   /* Find out how many images there are. */
   var testimg = $(this).find('.scrolling img').length;

   /* Do the maths. */
   var final = (test* testimg)*1.2;

   /* Apply the maths to the CSS. */
   $(this).find('scrolling').width(final); 
});
```

Here you loop through all your div's with class **target** and you do the calculations. Within this loop you can simply use `$(this)` to indicate the currently selected `<div>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

What about `.each()`?

http://api.jquery.com/each/

Answer (score 0):

Just as we refer to `scrolling` class

```
$( ".scrolling" ).each( function(){
    var img = $( "img", this );
    $(this).width( img.width() * img.length * 1.2 ) 
})
```