# create simple rotation with pause

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I cycle through a series of elements, adding a class, pausing then removing the class and moving on to the next element. I have tried setInterval and I have tried setTimeout, but cannot seem to get it to work.

My Javascript

```
var numpromos = $('.promoteBlock').length;
var promonum = 1;
while (numpromos > promonum){
    setInterval(function() { 
            $('#promoteCont .promoteBlock').fadeOut().removeClass('active');
            $('#promoteCont #promo'+promonum).addClass('active');   
        } 

    }, 3000);
    promonum++;
}
```

My HTML

```
<div id="promoteCont">
            <div id="promo1" class="promoteBlock">Promotion No.1</div>
            <div id="promo2" class="promoteBlock">Second Promo</div>
            <div id="promo3" class="promoteBlock">Another one</div>

         </div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery Loop through each div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8701650/jquery-loop-through-each-div)

Comment: Create a jsfiddle please. And we will help you..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function playNext(){
    console.log("playNext");
    var active = $('#promoteCont').find(".promoteBlock.active");
    if( active.length == 0 )
        active = $(".promoteBlock:eq(0)");

    var fout = active.next();
    if( fout.length == 0 )
        fout = $(".promoteBlock:eq(0)");

    active.fadeOut().removeClass('active');
    fout.fadeIn().addClass('active');

    setTimeout(function(){
        playNext();
    },3000);
}

setTimeout(function(){
    playNext();
},3000);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/p1c3kzj7/

Answer (score 1):

Take things out of the while loop.  You only need to set the interval once.  Perform your state calculation (which item is selected) within the callback method itself.  See below, which I believe is what your looking for.

```
// Global variables to maintain state... I'm sure I'll get some comments about these :p
var numpromos = $('.promoteBlock').length;
var promonum = 1;

$document.ready(function()
{
    setInterval(function() { 
        $('#promoteCont .promoteBlock').fadeOut().removeClass('active');
        $('#promoteCont #promo'+promonum).addClass('active');

        promonum++;

        if(promonums > numpromos)
          promonum = 1;           
    }, 3000);
});
```